# how to remove p tag (not empty) found after table

Tags: jquery

From certain live url I am dragging data for my work. Everything is working fine but I want data of p tag before table only and not after it. I mean data have following structure.

```
<p>some data</p>
<p>some data</p>
<table>
some data
</table>
<p>some data</p>
<p>some data</p>
<p>some data</p>
```

Now I want to retain first two p tags only along with table and no p tags or its data after table. How can I do this using Jquery. I tried doing finding p tag after table and then using remove but to no avail.
Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
$("table").nextAll("p").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) selector:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4aZ4/)

```
$("table").nextAll("p").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all next siblings it's :

```
$('table').nextAll('p').remove();
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Bdfq4/)**

You can also check out [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) just for selection purpose

```
$('table').prevAll('p')
```